# RadioButton Reset

Tags: c#, radio-button

I'm trying to create a reset button that resets a textbox and label to "".  Which I have done successfully, the next step is having the radio button being unchecked when the reset button is clicked.

```
private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTemp.Text = "";
    lblDisplay.Text = "";
    rbn1.AutoCheck = false;    
}
```

So basically to further clarify my problem, I have two radio buttons and when the reset button is clicked i want both of the buttons to be unselected.

Comment: rbn1.Checked = false;

Answer (score 2):

```
 rbn1.Checked = false;
 rbn2.Checked = false;
```